# When does the 13th doctor use points?

Tags: doctor-who

In the series 12 episode ‘Fugitive of the Judoon’ in response to someone (not going to say who!) saying something along the lines of ‘Well done, 5 points!’ the 13th Doctor says, ‘Don’t do points, points are my thing’.

My question is, are points her thing? I don’t remember a time when she references points in any previous episode. I haven’t watched the classic seasons of Doctor Who, so is this a reference to an older doctor?

Many thanks.

Comment: https://giphy.com/gifs/doctorwho-doctor-who-dr-series-12-WoivUmtd2JYaTFQaRZ

Comment: She's done it twice in twenty episodes

Comment: In the spirit of 'timey-whimey' she also does it in the following episode, Praxeus when she says *'Gold stars for my precious engineers'*. The 12th Doctor seems to use gold stars and points interchangeably.

Comment: Yeah, I did notice that when I watched it! Good to see at least a little bit of consistency.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In "The Tsuranga Conundrum," when Yaz locates the bomb on board the ship they're on:

> DOCTOR: Ten points for Yasmin Khan. And yes, I am keeping score, for all of you. Ronan, up your game. Jokes. So...

Then, in "Demons of the Punjab":

> PREM: What's she saying?
>   RYAN: If I had to guess, I think we're going demon hunting.
>   DOCTOR: Gold star for Ryan. Oh, wait. Was I awarding points? Oh, I forgot about the points.

Source: chakoteya.net

Comment: Oh wow, that’s so cool!

Comment: And note that she was back to gold stars again in Praxeus.